# CRM Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get() Returning Null

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I wrote javascript code and added it as a form on load event of entity(contact).  In that Code I want to navigate from the opening form to another form.

For previous developments, I'm trying to get the id of the opening form which I need in order to navigate.
Code as shown below.

```
  var id = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem().getId();

      if (itemid != null) 

    Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get(id).navigate();
```

`Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem()` function returns a null value.  It doesn't get the item so I can't get the value.  What's wrong with that code, what am I missing?

Thanks for replies in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why you are checking `itemid` in your `IF` condition while you have assigned the value to `id` variable?

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the value to `id` variable but checking `itemid` in your `IF` condition. 
In if condition just replace the `if (itemid != null)` with `if (id != null)`

To test your JavaScript. You can run following function:

```
var formItem = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem();
if (formItem != null)
{
    var itemId = formItem.getId();
    var itemLabel = formItem.getLabel();
    alert(itemId + " | " itemLabel);
}
else
{
    alert("Unable to get current form");
}
```

Finally, to switch between form, following is very useful function which takes the form name as parameter. you can make changes to use form Id if you like.

```
function redirectToForm(formName) {
    var currentForm = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem();
    if (currentForm != null) { 
        if (currentForm.getLabel().toLowerCase() != formName.toLowerCase()) { //make sure it's not already this form
            var availableForms = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get();
            for (var i in availableForms) {
                var form = availableForms[i];
                if (form.getLabel().toLowerCase() == formName.toLowerCase()) {
                    form.navigate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But my mainproblem Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get() function doesn't work.To navigate to from i have to use that code.i couldn't find any alternative way to do it

Comment: what result you are getting for `alert(Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get());`.

Answer (score 1):

In My case, i prefer send the form name as parameter of a kind function such as constructor via load form function.

in the javascript code:

```
var Formname = "Default";
    function Initialize(formname)
    {
      Formname = formname;
    }
```

In customization of Form, in the onload function, you set this variable and this way remove the dependece from for selector component.

I hope that this solution can help many.

Answer (score 0):

I took it up a notch and wrote the following post. You might find it interesting.
http://totbcrm.blogspot.co.il/2014/08/working-with-multiple-forms.html